# empty jms queue when pool is almost full

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, queue, jms

I'm currently writing a system where I'm making a connection between two applications. One of those applications sends messages to a glassfish jms queue. I haven't writen the receiver end yet and what I noticed is the queue will just fill up because there is no listener for the queue.

What I would love to do is check if the queue is almost filled up and when it is empty it completely. Is there a way to do this? I wasn't able to find anything really.

Or is it possible to make sure old messages get removed so new messages can keep being send?

Answer (score 1):

While there are, of course, practical limitations, a queueing system like JMS doesn't "fill up".  It is designed to have an "infinite" capacity.  Obviously you can't send an infinite number of messages without taking up resources so there is a practical limit.

It sounds like you need to define a [time to live](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html#setTimeToLive(long)) on the message producer side for messages that it produces.  So you could, for example, say that messages can only live 10 seconds.  In this way you are less likely to get "old" messages.  Note that depending on your JMS provider you still may get messages that are about the age of the TTL but you are not likely to get much older messages.

Comment: I just added the time to live option to my messages. I will have to test this tomorrow I will let you know if this solved my problem and if so ofcourse accept your awnser